# Publicar modificacion al web.config desde net core 3.1

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

tengo una app en Net Core 3.1 sobre Visual Studio 2019, y para esta aplicacion necesito agregar lo siguiente en el web.config que se publica:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
```

pero, eso lo hago manualmente cada que publico cambios, lei en varios blogs que es posible agregar un nuevo web.config en wwwroot y ahi personalizar lo que uno necesite, pero al publicar la app solo publica lo predeterminado y no lo agregado por mi persona.

Este es el web.config que agregue al proyecto, y es asi como quiero q se publique:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al publicar obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien puede guiarme que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

para los que tengan el mismo problema, este post describe la solucion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587544/asp-net-core-3-is-there-a-way-to-add-module-section-to-produced-web-config-fil